# Random SSH terminal disconnection Error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Tags: ssh

We get the error `kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host` randomly. Sometimes we are able to connect with our remote hosts.

As a workaround, we powered off and on our remote host, and this error `kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host` disappears.

Verbose logs:

```
$ ssh -vvvv -p 25899 sd@x.x.x.x
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/ghaza/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolving "x.x.x.x" port 25899
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to x.x.x.x [x.x.x.x] port 25899.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/ghaza/.ssh/id_rsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/ghaza/.ssh/id_rsa.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ghaza/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/ghaza/.ssh/id_rsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/ghaza/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ghaza/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/ghaza/.ssh/id_dsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/ghaza/.ssh/id_dsa.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ghaza/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/ghaza/.ssh/id_dsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/ghaza/.ssh/id_dsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ghaza/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/ghaza/.ssh/id_ecdsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/ghaza/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ghaza/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/ghaza/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/ghaza/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ghaza/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/ghaza/.ssh/id_ed25519 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/ghaza/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ghaza/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/ghaza/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/ghaza/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ghaza/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/ghaza/.ssh/id_xmss error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/ghaza/.ssh/id_xmss.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ghaza/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/ghaza/.ssh/id_xmss-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/ghaza/.ssh/id_xmss-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ghaza/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
```

Does anybody have any idea why we are having this issue?

Comment: You need to look at the logs on the _server_.

Comment: Which server logs? I have auth.log and syslog.